# Unity WebGL - Is there a way to clear all errors on build?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am wondering if there's a way to clear the error that pops up in the browser after the game is built?

I tried this code I found online, but it doesn't work as expected. I tried to put the script below in the Editor folder, but it didn't work as well.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
//using UnityEditor;

public class ClearConsole : MonoBehaviour
{


    public void ClearLog()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UnityEditor.Editor));
        var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.LogEntries");
        var method = type.GetMethod("Clear");
        method.Invoke(new object(), null);

    }

    void Update()
    {
        ClearLog();

    }
}
#endif
```

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: call `console.clear()` ?

Comment: @sommmen Hi thank you so much for your prompt response. How can I do this? I tried type out "console.clear()", but it seems that unity doesn't recognize the word "console".

Comment: In chrome i can simply type `clear()`